# Ubuntu 14.04/Kernel upgrade 4.0 no wireless

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Anyone know any solution for fixing wireless connection for TP-Link Tl821N, after upgrading to kernel 4.0, other than downgrading? No info on wireless adapter.

The icon of network in kde is red crossed, wifi connections don't appear on menu to connect, can't connect to Internet.

```
lsusb:
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 09da:9090 A4 Tech Co., Ltd XL-750BK Laser Mouse
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 045e:0750 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 600
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: 50:46:5d:09:ae:42
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:34 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff
```

Results from Wifi Diagnostic script: [Wifi Diagnostic](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10839814/)

Meanwhile, trying to see if the below works https://github.com/OpenELEC/OpenELEC.tv/blob/master/packages/linux-drivers/RTL8192CU/patches/RTL8192CU-kernel-4.0.patch

Comment: Would you know what to answer if I told you "My car just broke, what can I do?". You need to throw more than one line out there.

Comment: Kernel 4.0?? Thats barely released.

Comment: Sorry about that, kind of new to this world, the icon of network in kde is red crossed, info about interfaces edited, any tip on what to throw more in this cases?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: `lsusb`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help, shouldn't be searching for tp-link but RTL8192CU.

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very clear: There is a problem with all the 4.x Kernel line. That is the solution, reinstall the 3.19x kernel line to recover WIFI because there is no official solution for the moment to the problem: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1424676
An optional solution may be in this thread:
[How to compile bcmwl-ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612566/how-to-compile-bcmwl-ubuntu)

Comment: Thx for the info, it was a semi-fresh installation, so I formatted and installed again, now I'm on 4.0.0 and fixed wireless with the following:

 https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes

Answer (score -1):

Locate and install  network drivers, updated kernel does not supply proper drivers

Comment: It would be better if you could expand your answer and explain how someone would do that.