# How to compile bcmwl-ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, compiling

Running on kernel < 4.0 I used the precompiled bcmwl-kernel-source from the repository without any problems. Now I updated my Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS to kernel 4.0.0-040000-generic where the package isn't supported yet.
I found [this bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1424676) where the author describes that there is a patched version for kernel 4.0 [on github](https://github.com/longsleep/bcmwl-ubuntu).

Unfortunately I'm unable to compile it via `make all`. It gives me the following error:

```
user@computer:~/Downloads/bcmwl-ubuntu$ make all
KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
make[1]: Verzeichnis »/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.0-040000-generic«
wird betreten CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version Using
CFG80211 API   LD     
/home/user/Downloads/bcmwl-ubuntu/built-in.o make[2]: *** Keine
Regel vorhanden, um das Target
»/home/user/Downloads/bcmwl-ubuntu/src/shared/linux_osl.o«,   
benötigt von »/home/user/Downloads/bcmwl-ubuntu/wl.o«, zu
erstellen.  Schluss. make[1]: ***
[_module_/home/user/Downloads/bcmwl-ubuntu] Fehler 2 make[1]:
Verzeichnis »/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.0-040000-generic« wird
verlassen make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

Can anybody please advice me how to compile it or tell what I'm doing wrong?

- build-essential is version 11.6ubuntu6
- Wifi-Card is a BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter

Thank you!

Comment: no sprechen ze deutsch @Fabby can you assist?

Comment: @ElderGeek Deutsch, warum?

Comment: @ElderGeek ah, I see

Comment: @lumen, use this command for an english output `LANG=C` and post the error message again, but not as quote but as code.

Comment: @lumen Have you downloaded an archive, if so, which one, or do you cloned the repository?

Comment: @A.B.: Sorry, I thougt it was a common error update. I can't test it right now with the LANG-Parameter but I'm going to update it later.
The repository I cloned from the git master branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `make` is not right here. [longsleep](https://askubuntu.com/users/149781/longsleep) just [revised](https://github.com/longsleep/bcmwl-ubuntu/issues/1) the `README`:

> Guys this repository is ubuntu packaging. So you should build the
>   package and install it. It then builds the module with the kernel
>   patches required for your particular kernel version. I See that the
>   readme needs some work :-)

---

*This should work:*

First you need this package:

```
sudo apt-get install git-buildpackage
```

then change into `bcmwl-ubuntu` and start the package creation:

```
cd bcmwl-ubuntu
gbp buildpackage -b -uc -us
```

The deb package is a directory level above the build directory. E.G.:

```
../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-1longsleep0_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks good. [README](https://github.com/longsleep/bcmwl-ubuntu/blob/master/README) is updated now.

Comment: Thank you very much @A.B. and longsleep. With these instructions I was able to build and install the package successfully.

Comment: This has been great, getting me wireless on 3.14, 3.18 and now 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

In the meantime i created a ppa where one can easily install a Kernel 4.0 compatible version of the bcmwl package on Ubuntu 14.04, 14.10 and 15.04.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:longsleep/bcmwl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

So if you do not want to compile it yourself, grab it from there.

Check the ppa repository yourself at:  https://launchpad.net/~longsleep/+archive/ubuntu/bcmwl

Comment: Absolutely fantastic - works perfectly on the Dell XPS13 Developer's Edition 2015 (9434, I think). I'd updated my Kernel to 4.0 to resolve trackpad issues on this laptop, but it's use of a Broadcom BCM4352 WIFI card really trips this up. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

From https://askubuntu.com/a/613454/167385:

> In the meantime i created a ppa where one can easily install a Kernel
>   4.0 compatible version of the bcmwl package on Ubuntu 14.04, 14.10 and 15.04.
>
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:longsleep/bcmwl sudo apt-get update sudo
>   apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
>
> So if you do not want to compile it yourself, grab it from there.
>
> Check the ppa repository yourself at:
>   https://launchpad.net/~longsleep/+archive/ubuntu/bcmwl

Comment: Please don't copy other posts without quoting sources. http://askubuntu.com/a/613454/167385

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to compile it, longsleep uploaded a deb file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6FmWGouUs0YVVNGSU9RamRQVzQ/view)

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy31, I'm going to try it. Nevertheless it would be interessting how it can be compiled.

Comment: I am not sure what all the problems are at this time.  It does say that `/home/user/Downloads/bcmwl-ubuntu/src/shared/linux_osl.o` is missing but it is actually in `/home/user/Downloads/bcmwl-ubuntu/src/src/shared/linux_osl.o` and if you do copy it into the correct directory, compiling it results in undeclared function errors

Comment: I do not even remember uplading this package here. You should not use it and rather build the package yourself. As there seems to be sudden interest in this package i will provide details asap.